# Logic and formal reasoning

Tags: logic

What is the natural deduction form for this proof: $A\rightarrow(B\rightarrow C)\vdash(A\land B)\rightarrow C$ ? but I can't seem to figure out the starting point for it. I have tried the implication but it doesn't seem to work here.

Comment: Hint: conjunction elimination ($\wedge E$) will be crucial to the proof.

Answer (score 1):

$\def\fitch#1#2{\begin{array}{|l}#1\\\hline#2\end{array}}$

> but I can't seem to figure out the starting point for it.

Your goal is a conditional.   So start by assuming the antecedant and showing that will entail the consequent.

You then have a premise with two conditionals, and an assumption with a conjunction of two terms.   The sub-proof will undoubtably involve the Conjunction Eliminaton and Conditional Elimination rules.   So can you see where to use them?

$$\fitch{A\to (B\to C)\hspace{5ex}\text{Premise}}{\fitch{A\wedge B\hspace{12ex}\text{Assumption}}{~\\ ~\\ ~ \\ C\hspace{16.5ex}\text{for various reasons}}\\ (A\wedge B)\to C\hspace{6ex}\text{Conditional Introduction}}$$